# Which line of XML was invalid

Tags: c++, xml, qt, validation, xsd

I have got a schema and an XML. I am using QXmlSchemaValidator to check if the document is valid or not ( http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlschemavalidator.html ) and I get the proper answer. I am also displaying whole xml in the QPlainTextEdit.

But I would like to highlight the line in QPlainTextEdit where the problem occurred. Is there any way I could get the line number where validator sees the problem? As I can see in documentation, it returns only true/false

Comment: Sometimes it's non-trivial. If you're missing an element, do you report it at the opening parent tag or the corresponding closing tag? There can be even more complex grammars, especially with XPath expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple class you can use for XML schema validation:

```
#include <QAbstractMessageHandler>

class QXmlSchemaValidatorMessageHandler : public QAbstractMessageHandler
{
public:
    QXmlSchemaValidatorMessageHandler() : QAbstractMessageHandler(0) {}

    QString statusMessage() const { return m_description; }
    int line() const { return m_sourceLocation.line(); }
    int column() const { return m_sourceLocation.column(); }

protected:
    virtual void handleMessage(QtMsgType type, const QString &description,
        const QUrl &identifier, const QSourceLocation &sourceLocation)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(type);
        Q_UNUSED(identifier);

        m_messageType = type;
        m_description = description;
        m_sourceLocation = sourceLocation;
    }

private:

    QtMsgType m_messageType;
    QString m_description;
    QSourceLocation m_sourceLocation;
};
```

To use it, first, set it on the XML validator:

```
QXmlSchemaValidator validator(mySchemaUrl);

// validator does NOT take ownership of the handler, 
// so make sure to properly handle its lifetime if you decide to use a ptr
QXmlSchemaValidatorMessageHandler handler;
validator.setMessageHandler(&handler);
```

Then, you can format the message output to be human-readbale if the schema doesn't validate:

```
// it's invalid!
if (!validator.validate(myXml))
{
    // these messages are usually html, and it messes up the formatting, 
    // so use this regex to strip it out.
    QString errorMsg = handler.statusMessage().remove(QRegExp("<[^>]*>"));  
    std::cout << "ERROR: xml file is invalid at: line: " << handler.line() << ", column: " 
        << handler.column() << " - " << errorMsg.toStdString() << std::endl;
}
```

The `msg.line()` output could be used to find the line in your text edit to highlight it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can set a message handler that will provide messages during the validation.

```
void QXmlSchemaValidator::setMessageHandler ( QAbstractMessageHandler * handler )
```

> Changes the message handler for this QXmlSchemaValidator to handler. The schema validator sends all parsing and validation messages to this message handler. QXmlSchemaValidator does not take ownership of handler.

One of the message arguments is `const QSourceLocation & sourceLocation` which will identify where the error occured.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for the [Validator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlschemavalidator.html), if you set your own message handler, you will be able to get more info, such as the line number of the problem.

As it is stated for [setMessageHandler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlschemavalidator.html#setMessageHandler)

> When QXmlSchemaValidator calls QAbstractMessageHandler::message(), the arguments are as follows:
>
> ...
>
> const QSourceLocation & sourceLocation

[QSourceLocation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsourcelocation.html) provides the [line](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsourcelocation.html#line) function, which returns the line number which, in this case, failed validation